# Layout not working as planned

Tags: css, layout, sass

I'm trying to put together a nice layout for our company directory, where I display the employee pic on the left and Name, Description and MoreInfo Link stacked on top of each other.

I'm using bootstrap 3.

The problem I'm having is that the MoreInfo link is displaying under the image, and not below the description as I want.

Here is a code example:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">

      <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="" style="margin-top:0; margin-right:15px;" class="pull-left">

      <div>
        <h4 style="font-weight: bold; font-size:1.5em;">Zara Alipat, Ph.D.</h4>
        <span>
           Zara was born in western Niger, where the few girls who are lucky enough to attend school are pulled out at the age of 12 to get married. Despite the odds, Zara fought to complete her education and enter the professional workforce. Now she holds a Master’s degree, manages Mercy Corps’ human resources in Niger and uses her position to mentor other young people. 
        </span> 
        <p>
          <a href="#">Read Full Bio</a>
        </p>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">

      <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="" style="margin-top:0; margin-right:15px;" class="pull-left">

      <div>
        <h4 style="font-weight: bold; font-size:1.5em;">Zara Alipat, Ph.D.</h4>
        <span>
           Zara was born in western Niger, where the few girls who are lucky enough to attend school are pulled out at the age of 12 to get married. Despite the odds, Zara fought to complete her education and enter the professional workforce. Now she holds a Master’s degree, manages Mercy Corps’ human resources in Niger and uses her position to mentor other young people. 
        </span> 
        <p>
          <a href="#">Read Full Bio</a>
        </p>
      </div>

    </div>


  </div>
```

Any suggestions, or examples of good layout for this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="" style="margin-top:0; margin-right:15px;" class="img-responsive">
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-8">
        <h4 style="font-weight: bold; font-size:1.5em;">Zara Alipat, Ph.D.</h4>
        <span>
           Zara was born in western Niger, where the few girls who are lucky enough to attend school are pulled out at the age of 12 to get married. Despite the odds, Zara fought to complete her education and enter the professional workforce. Now she holds a Master’s degree, manages Mercy Corps’ human resources in Niger and uses her position to mentor other young people. 
        </span> 
        <p>
          <a href="#">Read Full Bio</a>
        </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Try using an additional col call on a div around your image. That way your items are acting like columns and your content will respect each other. I added an additional row wrapper to take care of the padding that comes from the col call on the divs. Play around with the numbers on the inside columns to fit your want. I also put img-responsive on the img call to make sure that it doesn't bleed over the column.

Comment: I would also remove your margin on the img, as your col padding will take care of what you're trying to do there.

Answer (score 0):

try put the image in one div and the name and moreinfo  in another 
make the image div non floating

```
  style="float:none;"
```